# How to create brush stroke on one side of shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

I'm creating a logo for a client and one idea I've had is below. I want to create brush strokes on one end of the two shapes below the T. One image below is the original, the other is my attempt at adding a brush stroke.

At the moment the stroke has been added by expanding a brush stroke and basically trying to position the end of the stroke over the shape (really messy,  you may be able to see that it's not really perfect.

Is there an easier way to do this? To essentially taper one end of the curled shape to look like a brush stroke?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

- From a vertical path, **Menu Effect** > **Distort & Transform** >
  **Roughen**
- **Menu Object** > **Expand Appearance**
- **Pen Tool** > Click on the top point and holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> click on the left, down and right to close the shape (Use the **Smart Guides**)
- Fill the new shape with 100% black, stroke: none.
- **Direct Selection Tool** > Click the left segment and move it to the left until make a rectangle
- Drag this shape to the **Brush Panel** > Select **Art Brush**

[image: Brush]

[image: T]